# What value is used to set document.domain in browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

What determines the value of document.domain property on page? It seems like it's not always equal to the root url domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.domain` contains the complete domain (including subdomains) from which the page was downloaded. You can set it manually to a parent domain. E.g., you can set the domain of a document loaded from `subdomain.example.com` to `example.com`. `<iframe>`s may have a different domain than the domain in the url bar.

Comment: Is it possible to set domain from the backend though?

Comment: Not directly, you can only prevent the document from setting its own domain with a document-domain HTTP header. You can let your backend render a page with a script tag like `<script>document.domain = ...</script>` though